# How can I model an object that fracture under force after 3d printing

Tags: modeling

I'm building a cone for 3D printing. After it's printed and used, it must be pulled apart to free the contents. How could I weaken an existing blender model to then build a printable object that will split apart when I pull it apart. Like pulling a pre-scored paper cup apart.

What's the best blender object modelling approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how exactly result should looks like or what is the purpuse (usage) of your Cone ... but something with perforation can be done like ...

- Add Cone object

[image]

- *Duplicate* Cone, *Delete > Faces Only,* *Subdivide* few times,add *Particle system > Hair > Emission from Vertices*, *Number* same as number of vertices, disable *Random order*, *Render as Object* ... Add *Cube* and scale it to something thin ... search for *Make Instances Real*, *Join* all Cubes

[image]

- to the first *Cone* add *Solidify* modifier and *Booean* modifier > *Difference > Object* choose joined Cubes object

[image]

Note: it is  just a concept ... bottom part would need probably separate particle system with particle object sqeezed in Y or Z axis to follow bottom edge ...

### **Edit:**

To just make some parts thinner the simplest way is probably to ...

- Delete top face, add *Solidify* modifier, *Apply*
- Select faces in place you want to make thinner and *Inset* <kbd>I</kbd> face
- Select others and *Repeat Last Operation* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Than move select central edges and move them closer to outer side to make it thinner in that place and refine top edge

[image]

Comment: Thank you. My needs might be simpler. And  I need to 3D print the model. My cone is 75cm high and 17cm across at the top. It holds a foam carrier which holds a plant seed. When the seed has grown to a small plant, the cone must be separated from the plant and roots tangled around it. The cone has only 4 struts from the top circle to the small bottom circle. I wanted a method in blender to weaken faces at critical structural point, such that the cone would break apart when horizontal forces were applied.  Does using the bool tool to reduce face area make sense? Thank you.

Comment: Edit ... next time  please use some illustration ... one image say more than thousands words :)